# Adding units to font-size and line-height variables in font shorthand

Tags: sass

I try to learn SASS. In order to compile my files, I use Prepros app. It worked well until I started to use mixins. My code is as follows:

```
@mixin fontface($size) {
    font: ($size)px/($size*1.7)px "Roboto Slab", Georgia, sans-serif;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
@include fontface(28);
```

When I compile it, I got spaces added to variables, like this:

```
font: 28 px/47.6 px "Roboto Slab", Georgia, sans-serif;
```

How can I change it? Is it because the app, or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're hard coding the line-height with a unit size, rather than just using it unitless (eg `28px/1.7`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to add a unit is via multiplication.  However, you need to turn one of the values into a string in order to prevent division in the shorthand:

```
@mixin fontface($size) {
    font: #{$size * 1px}/#{$size * 1.7px} "Roboto Slab", Georgia, sans-serif;
}
```

Instead, you may want to just apply the unit before passing it to the mixin:

```
@mixin fontface($size) {
    font: #{$size}/#{$size * 1.7} "Roboto Slab", Georgia, sans-serif;
}

.foo {
  @include fontface(10px);
}
```

Or use a unitless line-height:

```
@mixin fontface($size) {
    font: #{$size}/1.7 "Roboto Slab", Georgia, sans-serif;
}

.foo {
  @include fontface(10px);
}
```